# How to generate a new random number (that's different from the previous random number)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the following (that currently returns a random number from an array), so that each random number is different from the last one chosen.

```
function randomize(arr) {
            return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
        }

oracleImg = [];
          for (var i=1;i<=6;i++) {
          oracleImg.push(i);
        } 

randOracleImg = randomize(oracleImg);
```

I tried the following, but it's not always giving me a number different from the last number.

```
function randomize(arr) {
    var arr = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length);
    if(arr == this.lastSelected) {
          randomize();
        }
        else {
            this.lastSelected = arr;
            return arr;
        }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If it's always different from the previous number then it isn't really random.

Comment: Is it OK for the number to be the same as the second-last one, or is the real requirement to process the entire array in random order?

Comment: Not at all. You're choosing a random number from [0, arr.length).

Comment: You need a to hold onto the last generated number and have a loop that generates numbers, that continues until it gets one that is different from the last.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, it's fine if it's same as the second-last one.

Comment: @AndrewL. not if I use this to choose a random number from a given array.

Comment: You aren't returning the result of calling randomize recursively.

Comment: No but you're reassigning a number to an array. You're just finding index, use subscript to find it in the array

Comment: When you call `randomise()` recursively you don't pass the `arr` argument, nor do you do anything with its return value... Also, what is `this`?

Comment: @stark Can you explain?

Comment: return randomize(arr)

Comment: @stark you're proposing an infinite loop, it crashes.

Comment: @bhspencer I thought I'm doing that with `this.lastSelected = arr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing function's recursive `randomize()` call doesn't make sense because you don't pass it the `arr` argument and you don't do anything with its return value. That line should be:

```
return randomize(arr);
```

...except that by the time it gets to that line you have reassigned `arr` so that it no longer refers to the original array. Using an additional variable as in the following version should work.

Note that I've also added a test to make sure that if the array has only one element we return that item immediately because in that case it's not possible to select a different item each time. (The function returns `undefined` if the array is empty.)

```js
function randomize(arr) {
    if (arr.length < 2) return arr[0];
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length);
    if(num == this.lastSelected) {
        return randomize(arr);
    } else {
        this.lastSelected = num;
        return arr[num];
    }
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(randomize(["a","b","c","d"]));
});
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
```

Note that your original function seemed to be returning a random array *index*, but the code shown in my answer returns a random array *element*.

Note also that the way you are calling your function means that within the function `this` is window - not sure if that's what you intended; it works, but basically `lastSelected` is a global variable.

Given that I'm not keen on creating global variables needlessly, here's an alternative implementation with no global variables, and without recursion because in my opinion a simple while loop is a more semantic way to implement the concept of "keep trying until *x* happens":

```js
var randomize = function () {
    var lastSelected, num;
    return function randomize(arr) {
        if (arr.length < 2) return arr[0];
        while (lastSelected === (num = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)));
        lastSelected = num;
        return arr[num];
    };
}();

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(randomize(["a","b","c","d"]));
});
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
```

Comment: They are looking to return the item in the array, not the index. Therefore, line 7 should be "return arr[num];".

Comment: @Feathercrown - True. I did allude to that in my answer. Although looking at the extra code that has now been added to the question the array seems redundant because all it contains is the numbers from 1 to 6, so why not just generate random numbers in that range rather than using the array?

Comment: Because this code might be used elsewhere where the difference would matter.

Comment: @Feathercrown - Fine, I've updated the answer to return the element. And included an implementation that doesn't use recursion, because for this type of "keep trying till *x* happens" type problem I think a simple while loop better reflects the concept.

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn I got it working, I must have been testing it in a funky online editor to begin with.

Comment: As a matter of style I would avoid shadowing the name `randomize`. Besides possible confusion, some IDEs/linters will complain, as they should. Why are you giving a name to the internal function anyway?

Comment: @torazaburo - Why? Probably because I started that function by copy/pasting the other version. But having the name there doesn't bother me, and there are other situations where the inner/returned function in an IIFE would need a name if not being assigned to a variable (though it doesn't help in this situation).

Comment: @torazaburo because the function needs to be called from elsewhere.

Comment: @AgentZebra - No, torazaburo was referring to the (inner) function being returned with the line `return function randomize(arr) {`, which could've been `return function (arr) {` without a name with no difference in behaviour.

Comment: @nnnnnn hmmm, ok, how would it know to run the function again without the function name?

Comment: The inner function is returned by the outer function (and the outer function is invoked *immediately* - note the `()` parens after its closing `}`). So the `var randomize` variable is assigned to reference the inner function regardless of whether or not the inner function expression includes a name or what that name is.

Answer (score 1):

Below code is just an example, it will generate 99 numbers and all will be unique and random (Range is 0-1000), logic is simple just add random number in a temporary array and compare new random if it is already generated or not.

```js
var tempArray = [];
var i=0;
while (i != 99) {
  var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 999) + 0);
  if (tempArray.indexOf(random)==-1) {
        tempArray.push(random);
        i++;
  } else {
    continue;
  }
}
console.log(tempArray);
```

Comment: Re-read the question. He just wants each number to be different from the **previous** one, not **all** previous ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ALWAYS return a different number from an array then don't randomize, shuffle instead!*

The simplest fair (truly random) shuffling algorithm is the Fisher-Yates algorithm. Don't make the same [mistake Microsoft did and try to abuse `.sort()` to implement a shuffle](http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html). Just implement [Fisher-Yates (otherwise known as the Knuth shuffle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
// Fisher-Yates shuffle:
// Note: This function shuffles in-place, if you don't
//       want the original array to change then pass a copy
//       using [].slice()
function shuffle (theArray) {
    var tmp;
    for (var i=0; i<theArray.length;i++) {
        // Generate random index into the array:
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random()*theArray.length);

        // Swap current item with random item:
        tmp = theArray[i];
        theArray[j] = theArray[i];
        theArray[i] = tmp;
    }
    return theArray;
}
```

So just do:

```
shuffledOracleImg = shuffle(oracleImg.slice());

var i=0;

randOracleImg = shuffledOracleImg[i++]; // just get the next image
                                        // to get a random image
```

How you want to handle running out of images is up to you. Media players like iTunes or the music player on iPhones, iPads and iPods give users the option of stop playing or repeat from beginning. Some card game software will reshuffle and start again.

> *note: One of my pet-peeves is music player software that randomize instead of shuffle. Randomize is exactly the wrong thing to do because 1. some implementations don't check if the next song is the same as the current song so you get a song played twice (what you seem to want to avoid) and 2. some songs end up NEVER getting played. Shuffling and playing the shuffled playlist from beginning to end avoids both problems. CD player manufacturers got it right. MP3 player developers tend to get it wrong.

Comment: Thanks I love this answer. Very simple and more logical.

Answer (score 1):

here is a version which will ensure a random number that is always different from the last one. additionally you can control the max and min value of the generated random value. defaults are max: 100 and min: 1

```
var randomize = (function () {
    var last;
    return function randomize(min, max) {
        max = typeof max != 'number' ? 100 : max;
        min = typeof min != 'number' ? 1 : min;

        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        if (random == last) {
            return randomize(min, max);
        }

        last = random;
        return random;
    };
})();
```